# Performance: UIImage vs UIView

Tags: ios, uiview, uiimage

Out of sheer interest:

Is there any difference, specifically in (theoretic) performance or memory usage between using a `UIImage` of 25x25 pixels, square, one color, png on the one hand, or a `UIView` of the same size and color?

Consider the Unread bullet in `Mail.app`. Would you use an image for that? Or a `UIView` with rounded edges?

An image takes more space, and resided in a `UIImageview`, and has a resolution dependency, but on the other hand, once it is loaded, it wouldn't make too much difference, would it?

Comment: I would choose UIView over UIImage. Loading an image is always more expensive than an UIView. I've experienced a case when loading 40x40 pixels icon which somehow takes 4MB in size (due to designer's mistake), and it drastically occupied the app's memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `UIImageView` then it requires image. Where if you use `UIView` you not need image, so it makes your application `light weight`. Second thing, large image takes more `memory to load`. So, it is always beneficial to use `UIView` instead of `image` wherever possible! It keeps your application light weight and can give better performance!

Answer (score 0):

An `UIImageView`, being a subclass of `UIView`, will instantiate a regular view with all the extension that UIKit developers have built to support displaying an image inside a plain UIView. By doing that you're only creating an **extended** (aka possibly heavier) version of a standard UIView.

That said, using an `UIView` for simple UI elements (like Mail.app's bullet icon) will also allow you to forget about the resolution of the graphical asset since you don't have to care about @2x or @3x resolutions resulting also in a **smaller project size**.

Of course you'll only save kilobytes when it comes to simple shapes, but reusing this pattern all across the app will benefit you exponentially in the long term.